# How to get country code from mobile number using libphonenumber api in Android

Tags: android, libphonenumber

I am using libphonenumber api https://code.google.com/p/libphonenumber/ in android project, I am getting country code using following code

```
PhoneNumberUtil phoneUtil = PhoneNumberUtil.getInstance();
try {
       PhoneNumber numberProto = phoneUtil.parse(number, "IN");
       int countryCode = numberProto.getCountryCode();
      } catch (NumberParseException e) {
         System.err.println("NumberParseException was thrown: " + e.toString());
      }
```

My question is:-
 -- I have number like +447870000000 but don't know about country code but want to get country code from this number like +44  how can I get it through this api ?

please help me
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

```
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
 {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.service_activity);

   /*********** read indicative sim *************/
     TelephonyManager telMgr =  (TelephonyManager)this.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

     String simContryiso = telMgr.getSimCountryIso();
     String indicative = Iso2Phone.getPhone(simContryiso);
 }



//create a class which contains the indicative of all the country and the ISO code
public class Iso2Phone
{

    // Get the indicative
    public static String getPhone(String code)
    {
        return country_to_indicative.get(code.toUpperCase());
    }

    private static Map<String, String> country_to_indicative = new HashMap<String, String>();
    static
    {
        country_to_indicative.put("AF", "+93");
        country_to_indicative.put("AL", "+355");
        country_to_indicative.put("DZ", "+213");
        country_to_indicative.put("AS", "+1684");
        country_to_indicative.put("AD", "+376");
        country_to_indicative.put("AO", "+244");
        country_to_indicative.put("AI", "+1264");
        country_to_indicative.put("AG", "+1268");
        country_to_indicative.put("AR", "+54");
        country_to_indicative.put("AM", "+374");
        country_to_indicative.put("AU", "+61");
        country_to_indicative.put("AW", "+297");
        country_to_indicative.put("AT", "+43");
        country_to_indicative.put("AZ", "+994");
        country_to_indicative.put("BS", "+1242");
        country_to_indicative.put("BH", "+973");
        country_to_indicative.put("BD", "+880");
        country_to_indicative.put("BB", "+1246");
        country_to_indicative.put("BY", "+375");
        country_to_indicative.put("BE", "+32");
        country_to_indicative.put("BZ", "+501");
        country_to_indicative.put("BJ", "+229");
        country_to_indicative.put("BM", "+1441");
        country_to_indicative.put("BT", "+975");
        country_to_indicative.put("BO", "+591");
        country_to_indicative.put("BA", "+387");
        country_to_indicative.put("BW", "+267");
        country_to_indicative.put("BR", "+55");
        country_to_indicative.put("BN", "+673");
        country_to_indicative.put("BG", "+359");
        country_to_indicative.put("BF", "+226");
        country_to_indicative.put("BI", "+257");
        country_to_indicative.put("KH", "+855");
        country_to_indicative.put("CM", "+237");
        country_to_indicative.put("CA", "+1");
        country_to_indicative.put("CV", "+238");
        country_to_indicative.put("CF", "+236");
        country_to_indicative.put("TD", "+235");
        country_to_indicative.put("CL", "+56");
        country_to_indicative.put("CN", "+86");
        country_to_indicative.put("CO", "+57");
        country_to_indicative.put("KM", "+269");
        country_to_indicative.put("CD", "+243");
        country_to_indicative.put("CG", "+242");
        country_to_indicative.put("CR", "+506");
        country_to_indicative.put("CI", "+225");
        country_to_indicative.put("HR", "+385");
        country_to_indicative.put("CU", "+53");
        country_to_indicative.put("CY", "+357");
        country_to_indicative.put("CZ", "+420");
        country_to_indicative.put("DK", "+45");
        country_to_indicative.put("DJ", "+253");
        country_to_indicative.put("DM", "+1767");
        country_to_indicative.put("DO", "+1829");
        country_to_indicative.put("EC", "+593");
        country_to_indicative.put("EG", "+20");
        country_to_indicative.put("SV", "+503");
        country_to_indicative.put("GQ", "+240");
        country_to_indicative.put("ER", "+291");
        country_to_indicative.put("EE", "+372");
        country_to_indicative.put("ET", "+251");
        country_to_indicative.put("FJ", "+679");
        country_to_indicative.put("FI", "+358");
        country_to_indicative.put("FR", "+33");
        country_to_indicative.put("GA", "+241");
        country_to_indicative.put("GM", "+220");
        country_to_indicative.put("GE", "+995");
        country_to_indicative.put("DE", "+49");
        country_to_indicative.put("GH", "+233");
        country_to_indicative.put("GR", "+30");
        country_to_indicative.put("GD", "+1473");
        country_to_indicative.put("GT", "+502");
        country_to_indicative.put("GN", "+224");
        country_to_indicative.put("GW", "+245");
        country_to_indicative.put("GY", "+592");
        country_to_indicative.put("HT", "+509");
        country_to_indicative.put("HN", "+504");
        country_to_indicative.put("HU", "+36");
        country_to_indicative.put("IS", "+354");
        country_to_indicative.put("IN", "+91");
        country_to_indicative.put("ID", "+62");
        country_to_indicative.put("IR", "+98");
        country_to_indicative.put("IQ", "+964");
        country_to_indicative.put("IE", "+353");
        country_to_indicative.put("IL", "+972");
        country_to_indicative.put("IT", "+39");
        country_to_indicative.put("JM", "+1876");
        country_to_indicative.put("JP", "+81");
        country_to_indicative.put("JO", "+962");
        country_to_indicative.put("KZ", "+7");
        country_to_indicative.put("KE", "+254");
        country_to_indicative.put("KI", "+686");
        country_to_indicative.put("KP", "+850");
        country_to_indicative.put("KR", "+82");
        country_to_indicative.put("KW", "+965");
        country_to_indicative.put("KG", "+996");
        country_to_indicative.put("LA", "+856");
        country_to_indicative.put("LV", "+371");
        country_to_indicative.put("LB", "+961");
        country_to_indicative.put("LS", "+266");
        country_to_indicative.put("LR", "+231");
        country_to_indicative.put("LY", "+218");
        country_to_indicative.put("LI", "+423");
        country_to_indicative.put("LT", "+370");
        country_to_indicative.put("LU", "+352");
        country_to_indicative.put("MK", "+389");
        country_to_indicative.put("MG", "+261");
        country_to_indicative.put("MW", "+265");
        country_to_indicative.put("MY", "+60");
        country_to_indicative.put("MV", "+960");
        country_to_indicative.put("ML", "+223");
        country_to_indicative.put("MT", "+356");
        country_to_indicative.put("MH", "+692");
        country_to_indicative.put("MR", "+222");
        country_to_indicative.put("MU", "+230");
        country_to_indicative.put("MX", "+52");
        country_to_indicative.put("FM", "+691");
        country_to_indicative.put("MD", "+373");
        country_to_indicative.put("MC", "+377");
        country_to_indicative.put("MN", "+976");
        country_to_indicative.put("ME", "+382");
        country_to_indicative.put("MA", "+212");
        country_to_indicative.put("MZ", "+258");
        country_to_indicative.put("MM", "+95");
        country_to_indicative.put("NA", "+264");
        country_to_indicative.put("NR", "+674");
        country_to_indicative.put("NP", "+977");
        country_to_indicative.put("NL", "+31");
        country_to_indicative.put("NZ", "+64");
        country_to_indicative.put("NI", "+505");
        country_to_indicative.put("NE", "+227");
        country_to_indicative.put("NG", "+234");
        country_to_indicative.put("NO", "+47");
        country_to_indicative.put("OM", "+968");
        country_to_indicative.put("PK", "+92");
        country_to_indicative.put("PW", "+680");
        country_to_indicative.put("PA", "+507");
        country_to_indicative.put("PG", "+675");
        country_to_indicative.put("PY", "+595");
        country_to_indicative.put("PE", "+51");
        country_to_indicative.put("PH", "+63");
        country_to_indicative.put("PL", "+48");
        country_to_indicative.put("PT", "+351");
        country_to_indicative.put("QA", "+974");
        country_to_indicative.put("RO", "+40");
        country_to_indicative.put("RU", "+7");
        country_to_indicative.put("RW", "+250");
        country_to_indicative.put("KN", "+1869");
        country_to_indicative.put("LC", "+1758");
        country_to_indicative.put("VC", "+1784");
        country_to_indicative.put("WS", "+685");
        country_to_indicative.put("SM", "+378");
        country_to_indicative.put("ST", "+239");
        country_to_indicative.put("SA", "+966");
        country_to_indicative.put("SN", "+221");
        country_to_indicative.put("RS", "+381");
        country_to_indicative.put("SC", "+248");
        country_to_indicative.put("SL", "+232");
        country_to_indicative.put("SG", "+65");
        country_to_indicative.put("SK", "+421");
        country_to_indicative.put("SI", "+386");
        country_to_indicative.put("SB", "+677");
        country_to_indicative.put("SO", "+252");
        country_to_indicative.put("ZA", "+27");
        country_to_indicative.put("ES", "+34");
        country_to_indicative.put("LK", "+94");
        country_to_indicative.put("SD", "+249");
        country_to_indicative.put("SR", "+597");
        country_to_indicative.put("SZ", "+268");
        country_to_indicative.put("SE", "+46");
        country_to_indicative.put("CH", "+41");
        country_to_indicative.put("SY", "+963");
        country_to_indicative.put("TJ", "+992");
        country_to_indicative.put("TZ", "+255");
        country_to_indicative.put("TH", "+66");
        country_to_indicative.put("TL", "+670");
        country_to_indicative.put("TG", "+228");
        country_to_indicative.put("TO", "+676");
        country_to_indicative.put("TT", "+1868");
        country_to_indicative.put("TN", "+216");
        country_to_indicative.put("TR", "+90");
        country_to_indicative.put("TM", "+993");
        country_to_indicative.put("TV", "+688");
        country_to_indicative.put("UG", "+256");
        country_to_indicative.put("UA", "+380");
        country_to_indicative.put("AE", "+971");
        country_to_indicative.put("GB", "+44");
        country_to_indicative.put("US", "+1");
        country_to_indicative.put("UY", "+598");
        country_to_indicative.put("UZ", "+998");
        country_to_indicative.put("VU", "+678");
        country_to_indicative.put("VA", "+39");
        country_to_indicative.put("VE", "+58");
        country_to_indicative.put("VN", "+84");
        country_to_indicative.put("YE", "+967");
        country_to_indicative.put("ZM", "+260");
        country_to_indicative.put("ZW", "+263");
        country_to_indicative.put("GE", "+995");
        country_to_indicative.put("TW", "+886");
        country_to_indicative.put("AZ", "+994");
        country_to_indicative.put("MD", "+373");
        country_to_indicative.put("SO", "+252");
        country_to_indicative.put("GE", "+995");
        country_to_indicative.put("AU", "+61");
        country_to_indicative.put("CX", "+61");
        country_to_indicative.put("CC", "+61");
        country_to_indicative.put("NF", "+672");
        country_to_indicative.put("NC", "+687");
        country_to_indicative.put("PF", "+689");
        country_to_indicative.put("YT", "+262");
        country_to_indicative.put("GP", "+590");
        country_to_indicative.put("GP", "+590");
        country_to_indicative.put("PM", "+508");
        country_to_indicative.put("WF", "+681");
        country_to_indicative.put("PF", "+689");
        country_to_indicative.put("CK", "+682");
        country_to_indicative.put("NU", "+683");
        country_to_indicative.put("TK", "+690");
        country_to_indicative.put("GG", "+44");
        country_to_indicative.put("IM", "+44");
        country_to_indicative.put("JE", "+44");
        country_to_indicative.put("AI", "+1264");
        country_to_indicative.put("BM", "+1441");
        country_to_indicative.put("IO", "+246");
        country_to_indicative.put("VG", "+1284");
        country_to_indicative.put("KY", "+1345");
        country_to_indicative.put("FK", "+500");
        country_to_indicative.put("GI", "+350");
        country_to_indicative.put("MS", "+1664");
        country_to_indicative.put("PN", "+870");
        country_to_indicative.put("SH", "+290");
        country_to_indicative.put("TC", "+1649");
        country_to_indicative.put("MP", "+1670");
        country_to_indicative.put("PR", "+1");
        country_to_indicative.put("AS", "+1684");
        country_to_indicative.put("GU", "+1671");
        country_to_indicative.put("VI", "+1340");
        country_to_indicative.put("HK", "+852");
        country_to_indicative.put("MO", "+853");
        country_to_indicative.put("FO", "+298");
        country_to_indicative.put("GL", "+299");
        country_to_indicative.put("GF", "+594");
        country_to_indicative.put("GP", "+590");
        country_to_indicative.put("MQ", "+596");
        country_to_indicative.put("RE", "+262");
        country_to_indicative.put("AX", "+35818");
        country_to_indicative.put("AW", "+297");
        country_to_indicative.put("AN", "+599");
        country_to_indicative.put("SJ", "+47");
        country_to_indicative.put("AC", "+247");
        country_to_indicative.put("TA", "+290");
        country_to_indicative.put("AQ", "+6721");
        country_to_indicative.put("CS", "+381");
        country_to_indicative.put("PS", "+970");
        country_to_indicative.put("EH", "+212");
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any way to get all these code from API ?

Answer (score 2):

A nice Library has been provided

https://github.com/hbb20/CountryCodePickerProject

In dependency add

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.hbb20:ccp:2.2.0'
}
```

then use this xml code

```
<com.hbb20.CountryCodePicker
    android:id="@+id/ccp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    fbutton:ccp_contentColor="@color/appcolor"
    fbutton:ccp_textSize="@dimen/_10sdp" />
```

It will automatically populate the list of country code and also u can search in it.

Comment: Hi i just used this but i can't get the carrier number from the full number. I tried registering it with the EditText

Answer (score 0):

If you have a number in a E164 format (in your case +447870000000) and you specify country code ISO in the parser, it will actually ignore the given iso code and do the formatting based on the number.

Country code ISO is needed when the number you give to the method is in national format.

As far as your code snippet goes, it should work.