# how we get the country code from region in android

Tags: java, android, kotlin, local, device

how we get the country code from the region of the device in android. we set the region Australia then get the country code from Australia. after that I set the region Egypt then get the country code from Egypt. how to possibly this. I set the region in the setting of the device.Please help me

Comment: you mean country phone code right

Comment: https://github.com/MichaelRocks/libphonenumber-android https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31578958/how-to-get-country-codecalling-code-in-android/48873912

Comment: May be it's help: https://github.com/hbb20/CountryCodePickerProject

Comment: This code is not working